# Expanding $\frac{1}{z^3-z}$

Tags: partial-fractions

How would I use partial fractions to expand the following equation?

$\frac{1}{z^3-z}$

I have tried changing re-writing that as:

$\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z+1)}$

But I have a problem finding the numerators of the fraction when written as:

$\frac{a}{z}+\frac{b}{z+1}+\frac{c}{z-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note

> $$a(z^2-1)+bz(z-1)+cz(z+1)=1$$

Setting $z=0$ we get $a=-1$, setting $z=1$ we get $c={1\over 2}$, setting $z=-1$ we get $b={1\over 2}$.

Comment: Why do we set z = 0?

Comment: @AmirOmidi becuase it makes the $b$ and $c$ terms disappear (anything times $0$ is $0$), so we can solve for $a$ quickly and easily without any worries about $b$ or $c$.

Comment: Ah Ok! Thanks this suddenly makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Note: for more complicated partial fractions - ones with more than just an integer on the right side - you'll need to do more work than this.

Comment: @DanUznanski not really, it mostly depends on the complicatedness of the polynomial, not the original denominator. If I only change the RHS, I can just scale the answers for RHS=1. It's the LHS that can really complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

If we add the three fractions we get in the numerator $a(z+1)(z-1) + bz(z-1) + cz(z+1) = (a+b+c)z^2 + (-b+c)z - a$.

Now set this equal to 1.